# Vue.js async components: how to fire the render function more than once

Tags: vue.js, components

I am using async components in a vue.js project, like this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components

Everything works correctly on the first load because my factory function fires. The factory function makes an ajax call, then returns the template to Vue. It also does some custom JS stuff.

My issue is that when a user wants to load that component again, the factory function does not fire again. It will only fire on the first load of the component.

For example, I have a component for each page on the website (Home, About, Contact, etc). When the user clicks on About for the first time, it's all good. But when they go to Contact, then back to About, Vue will not call the factory function, and instead inject what looks to be a cached version of the template.

I need my custom JS to fire again, because it's what triggers a lot of animations. Is it possible to fire the factory function multiple times, or do I need to think about restructuring, and if so, is there a a suggested way?

Comment: I don't think you really want to retrieve the template again. To get your animations to work, you should probably be working with the transition component.

Comment: Don't know how to help since you've shared no code, but I can say for certain loading a component again because thats how animations are triggered is not a good user experience.